# How to fix 'undeclared identifier' error in Indy?

Tags: delphi

I have downloaded Indy 10.4587 and I get 'undeclared identifier' error when I try to compile it and install it in Delphi 7.

```
type
  ADDRINFO = record
    ai_flags        : Integer;      // AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, AI_NUMERICHOST
    ai_family       : Integer;      // PF_xxx
    ai_socktype     : Integer;      // SOCK_xxx
    ai_protocol     : Integer;      // 0 or IPPROTO_xxx for IPv4 and IPv6
    ai_addrlen      : size_t;     <---------------------------------------------HERE
    ...
  end;
```

The error is in this file:
LIB\SYSTEM\IdWship6.pas(49) Fatal: Could not compile used unit 'IdWinsock2.pas'

How can I fix this bug?
Does anybody have the direct download link to a stable version?

---

It looks like the latest pseudo-stable version of Indy you can download may be 10.4587, which actually may be 10.4.587. There is no ReadMe or About file inside the archive to explain the version and release date. It can be downloaded from a 3rd party web site here: http://indy.fulgan.com

However, people are talking about a possible version 10.5.8. Please let me know if you have a real download link for this 'magic' version.

Edit:

I just downloaded v10.4587 and it doesn't compile.

Comment: Where is `size_t` defined? If nowhere then it is indeed undeclared.

Comment: @Altar, if you want more recent "magic" versions of Indy, you'll most likely have to upgrade from Delphi 7. Later versions of Indy don't support older versions of Delphi (the change to Unicode in D2009 and higher may be part of the reason).

Comment: Well the latest version of the sources don't build at all and I'm using the latest Delphi. There is more up right now than this suggests. I think a 64-bit FPC compatible Indy is in the works, but the problem is different than the problem above.

Comment: Indy already supports FPC 64-bit.  It is Delphi 64-bit that is in the works now.

Comment: @Alter: 10.5.8 is the current version number, whereas 4587 (now up to 4589) is the SVN revision number.

Comment: @Ken: why do you say Indy does not support older Delphi versions?  Indy still supports all the way back to Delphi 5.  Yes, the Unicode change was a major update, but much of that logic has been backported for the older Ansi-based versions.

Comment: @Remy, I actually thought I remembered reading something in the EMBT groups that *you* had written that said so. Obviously I was wrong. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google on "delphi 7 size_t" offers up a link wherein there is a workaround to define size_t as well as a note that an earlier revision of the indy lib than what you mention is the last one which can be built using delphi 7

see: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=48622

Answer (score -1):

size_t is an undefined type.
put

```
size_t = integer;
```

at the top

Comment: If you're going to define it yourself, at least define it as *unsigned*.

Comment: If I were going to define it, I would use unsigned integer. The problem was that the type is undefined, not that it was defined improperly. :P

Comment: Right. You're *introducing* that problem with your answer.