# Latest subversion sources of Indy 10 won't build in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe

Just grabbed the latest sources from subversion, for Indy 10, and I get this error:

[DCC Error] IdWinsock2.pas(2421): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SIZE_T'

The code at IdWinsock2.pas line 2421 is:

```
  {$EXTERNALSYM WSACMSGHDR}
  WSACMSGHDR = record
    cmsg_len: SIZE_T;  // error.
    cmsg_level: Integer;
    cmsg_type: Integer;
    { followed by UCHAR cmsg_data[] }
  end;
```

This seems a pretty basic failure. I sort of expected the Indy sources to build in the latest Delphi, out of the box.  It must be something wrong on my end, but I don't know what.

It looks like the stable tagged sources indy10\Indy10\tags\Indy 10.5.7 works fine. It's just Trunk that's fried.

Update: To try to fix it, I added this:

```
type
  SIZE_T = Cardinal;
```

Then it dies later on in the same IdWinsock2.pas, at 6238:

```
function WSA_CMSGHDR_ALIGN(const Alength: SIZE_T): SIZE_T;
```

And it's external-sym defined at line 3218 differently:

```
  function WSA_CMSGHDR_ALIGN(const Alength: PtrUInt): PtrUInt;
```

My best guess is someone is in mid-hack on an attempt to make this work in a 64 bit FPC and hasn't noticed that they broke ability to compile it in shipping Delphi.

Comment: P: I like your new icon (I think).

Comment: I think you should submit your bug report to Indy, not to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually did this because someone else was asking about the stability of Indy. So I checked it out. The answer is. Not very stable.  But very actively developed.  Which is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIZE_T` support is currently in progress.  New code got checked in before it was ready, but it should be fixed shortly.

Comment: I was checking this because someone was asking about Indy 10.5.8, which I assumed mus mean Indy head revision.  Which isn't quite at a buildable state yet.  It is exciting to read the svn log and see the activity level is high.

Answer (score 2):

Warren, see [How to fix 'undeclared identifier' error in Indy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263641/how-to-fix-undeclared-identifier-error-in-indy)

This addresses that exact question, and has some notes about the versions of Delphi used to compile.

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare [size_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t) in Delphi as [Cardinal](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Cardinal):

```
type
  size_t = Cardinal;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me, unfortunately.  It seems that throughout the latest code in subversion, there is some kind of get-ready-for-big-refactor that is part way through.  Some times SIZE_T is a value type, and it's used all over as a value type, and in other places it's used as a pointer type.

Comment: @Warren Take a look at this [Remy response](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=328760#328760) on the Embarcadero forums, the correct place to define it is in IdIConv.pas.  Maybe there's no big re-factoring but just a bug or regression.  I don't have custom ports access here to look at the svn history, but it worths a view to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. good info.   It looks like 64 bit readiness (SIZE_T) changes were in a middle commit stage yesterday.